# SeekBar Stops Activity | What is the error?

Tags: android, seekbar

I design and implement a seek bar which incements by 50. But if i run app it is crashing. There is no syntax error (Eclipse does not notice me about this) What is the problem?

```
package com.example.hello;
import com.example.hello.R.layout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewPlan extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_plan);

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    seekBar.setProgress(0); //this is line 19
    seekBar.incrementProgressBy(50);
    seekBar.setMax(5000);


    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        TextView seekBarValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seekBarValue);
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progress / 50;
            progress = progress * 50;
            seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });




}

}
```

### new_plan.xml

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="77dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/seekBarValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

---

### LOG WINDOW:

```
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hakkikonu.dailycalorie/com.hakkikonu.dailycalorie.NewPlan}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at com.hakkikonu.dailycalorie.NewPlan.onCreate(NewPlan.java:19)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-24 21:52:50.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2236):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is line 19 in NewPlan.java

Comment: Where is line 19 of NewPlan.java?

Comment: @RaghavSood seekBar.setProgress(0);

Comment: @hakiko You don't have a view with the ID `seekbar` in the currently inflated layout

Comment: @Code-Guru seekBar.setProgress(0); also i showed it in code

Comment: @hakiko `seekBar` is `null`.

Comment: @Code-Guru i am new and i could not understand your terms for now. Could you implement correct part of this code.

Comment: @hakiko `Could you implement correct part of this code` No. StackOveflow is not a code generation service. If you are new, you should be willing the learn. googling `NullPointerException` would have given you the same answer both I and Code-Gure did in a few seconds. Also, if you don't know what is meant by "`seekbar` is `null`", I suggest you learn the basics of programming before coming to Android.

Comment: I know what is the seekbar is null but. My code has not any syntax error. I cleaned project and re-generate R.java but i still have same problem. :)

Comment: @RaghavSood Also i set initial value (0) for seekbar. How it can be null?

Comment: `null` is usually a runtime problem and not a syntax error. By using setProgress(), you're trying to set the value of a variable inside the SeekBar class, without having an instance of the SeekBar class. Your `seekBar` variable is null.

Comment: @hakiko You attempt to set the initial value of the *progress attribute* of the `seekBar` object, but this fails due to the NPE error. The `seekBar` reference itself is `null` because you failed to retrieve the View object at the previous line (line 18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
```

to:

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
```

Your ID in the XML file is `seekBar`. Java is case sensitive.

Comment: @hakiko probably because you have another View with an ID of `seekbar` in another file, so as far as eclipse knows you're referencing something that exists.

Comment: This is the first project for me on my new laptop. Sometimes R.java can't understand somethings and i usually clean related project to refresh all. For this error i did same steps but somehow it did not notice me. For your valuable time and interest, thanks. See you in other questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Java code can't find the View that should have the id `seekbar`. You should also double-check the ids used in `new_plan.xml`. I suggest also cleaning your project and rebuilding. From my experience, some changes don't force `R.java` to be generated and then you will see confusing issues when referencing members of `R` from your Java code.

Comment: I cleaned my project but still i have this problem. Also i check my .xml everything is fine.

Comment: @hakiko Since you still get an NPE, everything is probably not fine. Please edit your quesiton with the `new_plan.xml` file.

Comment: @hakiko You have an id named `seekBar`, but not one named `seekbar`. (See the difference?)